# How can you prove an inductive case of $n^2 < 2^n$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, proof-writing, induction

I'm trying to prove that $n^2 < 2^n$. I see this proof question from the example of 2.5.3 [here](https://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi3/sec_seq-induction.html).

I understand that when you prove an inductive case where $P(k+1)$ is true, you have first to assume the base case where $k^2 < 2^k$ is true.

Based on the base case assumption, you have to consider the case where $(k+1)^2 < 2^{k+1}$. In the linked article, it says, "To prove such an inequality, start with the left-hand side and work towards the right-hand side:"

And I can't understand the calculation flow. I understand $(k+1)^2$ to the second power is expanded, and you get $k^2 + 2k + 1$. And the article says by the inductive hypothesis, you get "${} < 2^k + 2k + 1$, which confuses me: I can't understand what is happening here. I can't understand why the $=$ sign changes into $<$. And the following flow makes me confused further: ${} < 2^k + 2^k$, which is derived from "since $2k + 1 < 2^k$ for $k \geq 5$," to which I wonder where $2k + 1$ came from. And the calculation flow in the article reaches "${} = 2^{k+1}$".

I am sure that my description here is unclear so I will attach the part of the article below. The explanation of the article says $(k+1)^2 < 2{k+1}$, which I can't follow. Could you please explain why and how you can prove that $P(k+1)$ is true?

[image: Image of page from textbook.]

Comment: You do know that $(k+1)^2 = k^2 + 2k + 1$, don't you?  Becasue that *is* an equality you use an equal sign.   Induction hypothesis is $k^2 < 2^k$.   SO that means $k^2 + \text{Barbar the elephant} < 2^k + \text{Barbar the elephant}$.  If instead of $\text{Barbar the elephant}$ we used $2k + 1$, we'd get $k^2 + 2k+1 < 2^k + 2k+1$.  You aske where the $2k+1$ came from.  It came from $(k+1)^2 = k^2 + \color{red}{2k+1}$.   So we have $(k+1)^2 = (k+1)(k+1)=(k+1)k + (k+1)1 = k^2 +k + k + 1 = k^2 + 2k+1=k^2 +\color{red}{2k+1}< 2^k +\color{red}{2k+1}$

Comment: You mean $n^2<2^n?$ Hard to read your question

Comment: I guess the second part is how do we know that $\color{red}{2k + 1} < \color{blue}{2^k}$.  Well, $k \ge 5$ so ... actually, the link you post to just assumes that is obvious.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the difficult-to-read parts of my post.  
Yes, I know that (k+1)² = k ² + 2k + 1.

Comment: So we are assuming $\color{red}{k^2}<\color{red}{2^k}$ and we need to prove $(\color{red}k\color{green}{+1})^2<2^{\color{red}k\color{green}{+1}}$. And $(\color{red}k\color{green}{+1)}^2=\color{red}{k^2}+\color{green}{2k+1}<\color{red}{2^k}+\color{green}{2k+1}$. Now $\color{blue}2\color{orange}k+\color{purple}1<\color{blue}2\color{orange}k+\color{purple}k=\color{green}3\color{orange}k<\color{green}k\color{orange}k=\color{red}{k^2}$ and we know $\color{red}{k^2}<\color{red}{2^k}$. so $\color{green}{2k+1<2^k}$ and $\color{red}{k^2}+\color{green}{2k+1}<\color{red}{2^k}+\color{green}{2^k}=2^{k+1}$

Comment: I still find it difficult to understand how you can prove that p(k+1) is true. From (k+1)², you get k ² + 2k + 1. To me, suddenly, “< 2 ᴷ + 2k + 1” appears. Could you explain why you can show the inequality sign < and how to get “2 ᴷ + 2k + 1”?

Comment: You do understand that the induction hypothesis is nothing more nor less than that we are assuming we know that $k^2 < 2^k$, right.  SO we *KNOW* that $k^2 < 2^k$.   That means $k^2 + \text{anything we want} < 2^k + \text{anything we want}$, right?   SO $k^2 + (2k + 1)< 2^k + (2k+1)$.

Comment: I understand the meaning of the induction hypothesis at last. Thank you for the clarification. So, if the base case is true, then you can extend it further to developed cases: you can add the same value to both the left and right sides of the equation.

Comment: I now find it difficult to understand where “2 ᴷ + 2 ᴷ” comes from. fleablood explained the calculation flow, but I still don’t understand. Could you explain it?

Comment: Well, you know $2^{k+1} =2\times 2^k= 2^k + 2^k$.

Comment: ... and you should know that $k^2 > 2k+1$

Comment: I understand how you can get 2 ᴷ + 2 ᴷ: because it is about an exponent of base 2, the + 1 of the exponent part k means the initial 2 ᴷ × 2. And the 2 is 2 ᴷ, so you get 2 ᴷ + 2 ᴷ. Thank you for explaining it clearly.

Comment: Thank you for showing me the relevant question in the past, peterwhy. I need more time to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

The claim they are using is $2k+1 < 2^k$ for $k\geq 5$. And they assume it is clear. You can prove it with induction too. The induction step in that goes like (induction hypothesis: $2k+1<2^k$)

$$\begin{align}
2(k+1)+1 &= 2k+1 + 2 \\
&< 2^k + 2 \\
& \leq 2^k + 2^k \\
&= 2^{k+1}
\end{align}$$

Here in the last inequality we used $2 \leq 2^k$, which is clear when $k$ is positive.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, ploosu2. 
I feel like I understand, but I am not sure.
The inductive case is set based on an arbitrary assumption: in this case, 2k + 1 < 2 ᴷ. But other than this, all goes over my head. I will think about it.